# Scala +Spark+Dataframe Exception When i try to dynamically cast a column and assign sorting order

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, casting, comparator

I want to sort my dataframe using **selected columns by casting them from stringtype to prederred type and prederred order.** But even a simple casting of a column doesn't work and giving this exception. I am providing the sample code here.

```
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sparkify").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sparkContext =new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
    var df =  sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load("example-data.csv")
//    val colsToSort= List("age")
    df = df.sort( df.col("age").cast(IntegerType).desc)
    df.show()
    sparkContext.stop()
```

The simple csv looks like this

```
+-----+---+---+
| name|sex|age|
+-----+---+---+
|Alice|  f| 34|
|  Bob|  m| 63|
|Alice|  f| 14|
|  Bob|  m|  6|
+-----+---+---+
```

The detailed exception stack.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedException: Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: unresolvedalias(cast(cast(age#2 as decimal(20,0)) as int))
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAlias.dataType(unresolved.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SortOrder.dataType(SortOrder.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SortOrder.checkInputDataTypes(SortOrder.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:121)
```

What am i doing wrong?
Or what is the best way to dynamically declare a sorting expression based on multiple columns, with type casting and ordering.

Can anyone help me with this Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create the new column within the `sort` function -- you have to do it before the `sort`. Try something like this instead:

```
df.withColumn("age", $"age".cast(IntegerType)).sort($"age".desc)
```

If you want to use a variable for the column name, try this:

```
val colName = "age"
df.withColumn(colName, col(colName).cast(IntegerType)).sort(col(colName).desc)
```

Note that, unless you are joining two tables with the same-named column, you can generally leave off the `df.` in front of `col(...)`. You could even create the `sort` column before you create the `df` and it works fine:

```
val sortCol = col("age").desc
val df = ...
df.sort(sortCol)
```

In that way you can easily apply the same `sort` to multiple `DataFrames`

If you want to cast more than one column, you could just do:

```
df.withColumn(...).withColumn(...).withColumn(...)
```

Where each of the `withColumn` is a cast expression. Or you could do:

```
df.select($"age".cast(IntegerType), $"otherCol".cast(DoubleType), ...)
```

Comment: Let's say if i am using the first approach, is there anyway i can do this for a variable string which holds the column name rather string? The implicit doesn't work with variable, as well as `var colName = "age"
      df.withColumn(colName, df.col(colName).cast(IntegerType)).sort(df.col(colName).desc)`. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: This works perfectly for me: `val colName = "age"; df.withColumn(colName, df.col(colName).cast(IntegerType))`

Comment: Wait got error with the `sort`. Try this: `val colName = "age"; df.withColumn(colName, df.col(colName).cast(IntegerType)).sort(col(colName).desc)` -- Note not `df.col(colName)` but `col(colName)`.

Comment: Thanks. That was a big support.